# How to maintain stable frames-per-second while capturing real-time video in C#

Tags: c#, video-capture

I have written a C# program that captures video from a specialized camera through the camera manufacturer's proprietary API.  I am able to write captured frames to disk through a FileStream object, but I am at the mercy of the camera and disk I/O when it comes to the framerate.

What is the best way to make sure I write to disk at the required framerate?  Is there a certain algorithm available that would compute the real-time average framerate and then add/discard frames to maintain a certain desired framerate?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell much because of the lack of information.

What's the format? Is there compression?

How is the camera API sending the frames? Are they timed, so the camera will send the frame rate you asked for? If it is, you are really dealing with I/O speed.

If you need high quality, and are writing without compression, you could experiment some lossless compression algorithms to balance between processing and drive I/O. You could gain some speed if the bottleneck is with a high drive I/O.

For frames, there are ways to implement that. Normally frames have time-stamp, you should search on that, and discard frames that are so near of the other.

Let's say that you want 60 fps, so the space in ms between frames is 1000/60=16ms, if the frame you get has a time stamp of 13ms after the last, you can discard it and don't write to disk.

Comment: I am writing out raw frames.  No special format and no compression.  I am querying the camera in a loop.  I believe the bottleneck is indeed I/O, which could vary from computer to computer.  I need to know what sort of calculations I need to do to keep the fps constant.

Comment: You are kidding-me saying I/O will vary? :-)
If you don't use compression it can be a good time to start using, use loss-less compression algorithm, the most simple can achieve good results, without losing your original data, so your I/O transfer will be so reduced. 

I worked with HD cameras, and even on 720p I needed a separated HD to keep the I/O.

For the frames theres some way. Normally frames have time-stamp, you should search for that, and discard frames that are so near of the other. Its only a way of much.

Comment: I don't have a choice.  I need raw, uncompressed frames.

Comment: I don't think that, as the compression can be simple run-length compression, not MPEG, or a lossy compression. Anyway I edited my answer to give you some idea on how to discard the frames you "dint need" according to the frame-rate you want. But if limiting the frame-rate is not sufficient you have two choices: Using compression, or go to buying hardware, RAID, and go on.

Comment: limiting the frame rate is exactly what I want.  For example, I'm capturing from a camera and recording at 60 fps but I don't want to update the UI at that rate.  I just want to update the UI at maybe 20 fps or so. Right now I am in a loop and I capture as fast as the loop allows.  I want to be able to throttle it at a specified frame rate even if I can capture faster than that.  And if the disk I/O is too slow then I will need to drop frames.  But I need to know how to calculate this.

Comment: Did you read the last edit of my answer on how to calculate this!?

Answer (score 0):

In a perfect world, you would check the first second which gives you a number of frames per second that your system supports.

Say your camera is capturing 60 fps but your computer can really only handle 45 fps. What you have to do is skip a total of 15 frames per second in order to keep up. Up to here, that's easy enough.

The math in this basic case is:

```
60 / 15 = 4
```

So skip one frame every four incoming frames like so (keep frames marked with an `X`, skip the others):

```
000000000011111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555
012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789

XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX
```

Of course, it is likely that you do not get such a clear cut case. The math remains the same, it's just that you'll end up skipping frames at what looks like varying points in time:

```
// simple algorithm based on fps from source & destination
// which fails to keep up long term
double camera_fps = 60.0;
double io_fps = camera_fps;

for(;;)
{
  double frames_step = camera_fps / io_fps;

  double start_time = time(); // assuming you get at least ms precision
  double frame = 0.0;
  for(int i(0); i < camera_fps; ++i)
  {
    buffer frame_data = capture_frame();
    if(i == (int)frame)  // <- part of the magic happens here
    {
      save_frame(frame_data);
    }
    frame += frames_step;
  }

  double end_time = time();
  double new_fps = camera_fps / (end_time - start_time);

  if(new_fps < io_fps)
  {
    io_fps = new_fps;
  }
}
```

As this algorithm shows, you want to adjust your fps as time goes by. During the first second, it is likely to give you an invalid result for all sorts of reasons. For example, writing to disk is likely going to be buffered so go really fast and it may look as if you could support 60 fps. Later, the fps will slow down and you may find that your maximum I/O speed is 57 fps instead.

One issue with this basic algorithm is that you can easily reduce the number of frames to make it work within 1 second, but it will only reduce the fps (i.e. I update `io_fps` only when `new_fps` is smaller). If you find the correct number for `io_fps`, you're fine. If you went too far, you're dropping frames when you shouldn't. This is because `new_fps` is going to be 1.0 when `(end_time - start_time)` is exactly 1 second, meaning that you did not spend too much time capturing and saving the incoming frames.

The solution to this issue is to time your `save_frame()` function. If the total amount is less than 1 second within the inner loop, then you can increase the amount of frames you can save. This will work better if you can use two threads. One thread reads the frame, pushes the frame on an in memory FIFO, the other thread retrieves the frames from that FIFO. This means the amount of time to capture one frame doesn't (as much) affect the time it takes to save a frame.

```
bool stop = false;

// capture
for(;;)
{
  buffer frame_data = capture_frame();
  fifo.push(frame_data);
  if(stop)
  {
    break;
  }
}

// save to disk
double expected_time_to_save_one_frame = 1.0 / camera_fps;
double next_start_time = time();
for(;;)
{
  buffer frame_data = fifo.pop();
  double start_time = next_start_time;
  save_frame(frame_data);
  next_start_time = time();
  double end_time = time();
  if(start_time - end_time > expected_time_to_save_one_frame)
  {
    fifo.pop();  // skip one frame
  }
}
```

This is just pseudo code and I may have made a few mistakes. It also expects that the gap between `start_time` and `end_time` is not going to be more than one frame (i.e. if you have a case where the capture is 60 fps and the I/O supports less than 30 fps, you often would have to skip two frames in a row).

For people who are compressing frames, keep in mind that the timing of one call to `save_frame()` will vary a lot. At times, the frame can easily be compressed (no horizontal movement) and at times it's really slow. This is where such dynamism can help tremendously. Your disk I/O, assuming not much else occurs while you are recording, should not vary much once you reach the maximum speed supported.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** these algorithms suppose that the camera fps is fixed; this is likely not quite true; you can also time the camera and adjust the `camera_fps` parameter accordingly (which means the `expected_time_to_save_one_frame` variable can also vary over time).